# Difference between two times format in hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have two dates in database in unix time. I want the difference between them and show that in hours.

**For example**
Date1: 05/07/2016 14:40:00 PM  **(1467733205)**
Date2: 05/07/2016 15:40:05 PM  **(1467729600)**

**Difference:**
Date2 - Date1 = **3605 s**

That result I want to show him in hours. -> **1 hour and 5 seconds**

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + (((HOUR_DEPARTURE - DATE_LOADING )/ 60 / 60 / 24)), 'dd "days and" HH:MI:SS')
  FROM dual
```

I tried like this but it shous 01 days and 01:00:05 . There is not one day difference.

Comment: What format do you want for the answer? I hope you want 01:00:05, not what you wrote (a string: 1 hour and 5 seconds). Also, how do you want the result shown if the difference is 40 hours?

Comment: @AjayPunekar - It is not a duplicate; the question you linked to has nothing to do with formatting, which is the only problem here.

Comment: what does this have to do with [tag:c#] and [tag:asp.net]?

Answer (score 0):

The dd in your solution picks the day of the month from 01/01/1970. So you already start with 1 day. You can't simply subtract 1 to get "0 days" since the computations are done over calendar dates, not "number of days".

If you want the answer in days and hh:mi:ss then you can do something like this:

```
with
     test_data (date1, date2) as (
       select sysdate - 3605 / 86400, sysdate from dual
     )
select to_char(trunc(date2 - date1)) || ' days and ' || 
            to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (date2 - date1), 'hh24:mi:ss')
from   test_data;



TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DATE2-DATE1))||'DAYSAND'||TO_CHAR(DATE'1970-
----------------------------------------------------------
0 days and 01:00:05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    DECODE (d,  0, NULL,  1, '1 day ',  TO_CHAR (d) || ' days ')
       || DECODE (h,  0, NULL,  1, '1 hour ',  TO_CHAR (h) || ' hours ')
       || DECODE (m,  0, NULL,  1, '1 minute ',  TO_CHAR (m) || ' minutes ')
       || DECODE (s,  0, NULL,  1, '1 second',  TO_CHAR (s) || ' seconds')
  FROM (SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM (dt)) d, EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (dt)) h, EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (dt)) m, EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (dt)) s
          FROM (SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL (:HOUR_DEPARTURE - :DATE_LOADING, 'DAY') AS dt FROM DUAL))
```

For fun:

```
SELECT    DECODE (y,  0, NULL,  1, '1 year ',  TO_CHAR (y) || ' years ') 
       || DECODE (m,  0, NULL,  1, '1 month ',  TO_CHAR (m) || ' months ') 
       || DECODE (d,  0, NULL,  1, '1 day ',  TO_CHAR (d) || ' days ')
       || DECODE (h,  0, NULL,  1, '1 hour ',  TO_CHAR (h) || ' hours ')
       || DECODE (mi,  0, NULL,  1, '1 minute ',  TO_CHAR (mi) || ' minutes ')
       || DECODE (s,  0, NULL,  1, '1 second',  TO_CHAR (s) || ' seconds')
  FROM (SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (ym)) y,EXTRACT (MONTH FROM (ym)) m, 
               EXTRACT (DAY FROM (dt)) d, EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (dt)) h, EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (dt)) mi, EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (dt)) s
          FROM (SELECT NUMTOYMINTERVAL (MONTHS_BETWEEN (:HOUR_DEPARTURE, :DATE_LOADING), 'MONTH') AS ym ,
                       NUMTODSINTERVAL (ADD_MONTHS(:HOUR_DEPARTURE,-MONTHS_BETWEEN (:HOUR_DEPARTURE, :DATE_LOADING)) - :DATE_LOADING, 'DAY') AS dt 
                  FROM DUAL
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( date1, date2 ) AS
SELECT 1467733205, 1467729600 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( diff ) AS days,
       TRUNC( MOD( diff * 24, 24 ) ) AS hours,
       TRUNC( MOD( diff * 24*60, 60 ) ) AS minutes,
       ROUND( MOD( diff * 24*60*60, 60 ) ) AS seconds
FROM   (
  SELECT ( DATE '1970-01-01' + date1 /24/60/60 )
         - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + date2 /24/60/60 ) AS diff
  FROM   your_table
);
```

**Output**:

```
DAYS HOURS MINUTES SECONDS
---- ----- ------- -------
   0     1       0       5
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             (  ( DATE '1970-01-01' + date1 / 24/60/60 )
              - ( DATE '1970-01-01' + date2 / 24/60/60 ) ) DAY TO SECOND,
             '^\+?(-?)0*(\d+) 0?(\d+):0?(\d+):0?(\d+)\.0+$'
             '\1\2 days \3 hours \4 minutes \5 seconds'
           ),
           '(^| )0 (days|hours|minutes|seconds)'
         )
       ) AS difference
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

```
DIFFERENCE
-----------------
1 hours 5 seconds
```